# Problems with my class "Smart_pointer" and variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, smart-pointers, nullptr

I need your help. I have created a class "smart pointer" and a function that uses the variadic templates to simulate the new operator (reserve memory space).

```
    template <typename T>
    class smart_ptr{
    T* pointer = nullptr;
  public:
    explicit smart_ptr<T>(T* p = nullptr){
      pointer = p;
    }

    smart_ptr(T value){pointer = new T(value);}

    ~smart_ptr(){
      delete (pointer);
    }

    T& operator*(){return *pointer;}

    T* operator->(){return pointer;}
};

   template<typename T, typename ...Params>
   smart_ptr<T> make_smart_ptr(Params&& ...params) {
   return smart_ptr<T>(params...);
  }
```

However, when I test it with the following cases

```
smart_ptr<int> sp1; 
    sp1 = make_smart_ptr<int>(10);
    cout << *sp1 << endl;  //10

    smart_ptr<string> sp2 = make_smart_ptr<string>("Hello"); 
    cout << *sp2 << endl; //"Hello"
```

it only gives me the correct output which is "Hello" while in another it gives me 0 instead of 10 (below the results of my compilation and execution of the code).

```
0      //result of cout to sp1 (incorrect)
Hello  //result of cout to sp2 (correct)
```

Any help that you could give me to solve my code and that it runs in all cases. Thanks and good week.

Comment: Your class violates the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The assignment of `sp1` doesn't transfer ownership of the pointer, thus the allocated `int` gets freed prematurely before you can read from it. You need to implement proper move semantics in your class.

Comment: So, should I implement a copy constructor and its overload, in addition to a move constructor and its overload?

Comment: a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, and a move constructor and move assignment operator, yes. Also, `make_smart_ptr` should use `std::forward` when passing `Params` to `smart_ptr`'s constructor.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I could already solve the problem. Thank You for your support and information :D.